# How can I use a for loop to programmatically generate snakemake rules?

Tags: snakemake

I would like to use a for loop to generate a set of rules, based on the contents of of the `config.yaml` file. Here's a minimum working example.

```
config={'person1': 'Amy', 'person2': 'Bruce'}
                       
for thiskey,thisperson in config.items():
    rule:  
        name: f'{thisperson}s_rule'
        output: f'{thiskey}.txt'
        run:
            print(f'\n{thiskey} is called {thisperson}!\n')
            
rule people:
    input: [this+'.txt' for this in config.keys()]
```

If you run it (use the `-k` switch to keep going and ignore the missing files), you'll see that the same thing is being written to the screen for both files (`person2 is called Bruce!`) whereas you would expect to see a similar messages for both Amy and Bruce.

Is this at all a sensible way to setup rules? Or should I find a workaround?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config = {'person1': 'Amy', 'person2': 'Bruce'}

def create_rule(thiskey, thisperson):
    rule:
        name: f"{thisperson}s_rule"
        output: f"{thiskey}.txt"
        run:
            print(f'\n{thiskey} is called {thisperson}!\n')

# Generate rules
for thiskey, thisperson in config.items():
    create_rule(thiskey, thisperson)

rule people:
    input: [this + '.txt' for this in config.keys()]
```

TTry to pass the loop variables as default arguments to an inline function, forcing their evaluation at each iteration.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to use snakemake-specific syntax within a python function, and I didn't know about the "name" parameter of a rule. Interesting, thanks. That said, is there a more pythonic way to create a rule (i.e. using a class or function that creates a rule without having to use snakemake-specific syntax) ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your real case is more complex, but the typical way of implementing your example would not need to generate rules on the fly:

```
config={'person1': 'Amy', 'person2': 'Bruce'}
                       
rule people:
    input: 
        expand('{thiskey}.txt', thiskey=config.keys()), # same as: [this+'.txt' for this in config.keys()]

rule make_person:
    output:
        '{thiskey}.txt',
    params:
        thisperson=lambda wc: config[wc.thiskey],
    run:
        print(f'\n{wildcards.thiskey} is called {params.thisperson}!\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - this is a really nice example of how to use params:, which I've never quite understood until now. I may be able to use this approach anyway.